# Install redis.v5 on Go 1.7.5

Tags: go

In my project has dependence "gopkg.in/redis.v5"

and I get message:

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: cannot open file 

/usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/gopkg.in/redis.v5.a: open
/usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/gopkg.in/redis.v5.a: no such file or directory
```

I do command: `go get gopkg.in/redis.v5`

but directory `/usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/gopkg.in/`is not created:
Whats is the problem?

**updated**

```
GOPATH="/home/itcoder/go"

GOROOT="/usr/local/go"

GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
```

Comment: Probably you completely botch up your GOPATH. /usr/local/go is you Go installation and should **never** contain any non-stdlib packages, especially not something you "go get"ed. Show `go env`.

Comment: GOOS="linux"

GOPATH="/home/itcoder/go"

GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"

Comment: Did you do unnecessary `sudo` stuff? Try deleting /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64 and run `go get` with the  `-v` flag.

Comment: It is not helpme.  I running command, but files not created
But i Found /go/pkg/linux_amd64/gopkg.in this direcotry if I moved filed to /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64 all ok

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution!

Comment: Thank you very much